# Raspberry Pi Model B won't boot a working SD card

Tags: raspbian, boot, sd-card, boot-issues

I have the following:

- Raspberry Pi model B (call it rPi)
- A second Raspberry Pi model B (call it backup rPi)
- A micro SD card with adapter, the brand is SanDisk
- An SD card, brand is Lexar

The problem is that the rPi won't boot the micro SD card.

Additional info: The rPi used to boot this micro SD just fine. I guess the last time I used it was around a month ago or two, now it doesn't boot anymore. I tried to boot the same micro SD card on the backup rPi and it seemed that it was not working (but I'm not 100% sure about this statement). The Lexar SD card boots in both rPi and backup, and I want to point out that it was a copy of the former micro SD.

What I have tried: I installed a new version of raspbian on the micro SD using etcher as suggested on the instructions.

The current state of affairs:

- rPi only boots the Lexar SD, when plugged with the micro SD only the red PWR led lights up
- backup rPi boots both the SanDisk micro SD and the Lexar SD

I'm not sure how to proceed to further debug this problem. I know that I could simply use the micro SD on the backup rPi and the Lexar on the rPi, but in that case I would not trust any of the two to work safely.

UPDATE: I made a third raspbian using a microSD from my smartphone, the result is the same as the previous SanDisk card: boots on backup but not on rPi. I used the same microSD to SD adapter in both cases.

Comment: A long shot, but have a look at the second part of this, where there is a picture of the SD card holder: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/46233/5538

Comment: @goldilocks actually the long shot was very well worth it. Although neither the micro SD adapter nor the rPi slot present any visible physical damage, applying pressure on the card made it boot, possibly by forcing a pin connection (?). I'm trying to figure out how much I can trust this setup, but thanks for your help

Comment: Those contacts are springy, perhaps they are wearing out.